# Extract Patterns in an Integer Array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, pattern-matching

In short, my problem is to find several integer "patterns" in an integer array; the result should be optimal with respect to the total value of all the patterns extracted.

Specifically, elements of the array and the pattern are non-negative integers. We say a pattern can be extracted from the array if all elements in the array remain non-negative when the pattern is deducted from some consecutive elements (of same length as the pattern) of this array.

Since the elements are integers, every pattern can be extracted more than once, which is different from string patterns. For example, given an array = {1, 2, 1} and a pattern = {1, 1}, we can find two such patterns in the array: the first one is included in the first two items of the array {1, 2}, and after extracting one pattern from the array, the array becomes {0, 1, 1} then we can extract the second {1, 1} pattern from the last two items in the array.

Every pattern has a value; when a pattern is extracted i times, the value is also multiplied by i. The goal is to find a sequence of pattern extraction that maximize the total value in the end.

I tried to use a greedy algorithm, i.e., to extract the patterns with maximal unit value first, but there still exist a problem: if there are several max-value patterns in the array, which to  choose first? The greedy strategy used here reminds me of the Knapsack Problem, but they are different. Plus, the optimality of the greedy algorithm is dubious. I was thinking of a Dynamic Programming algorithm but am totally blank now.

Hope I've made the problem clear. Any suggestions?

Comment: It could be easily solved by dynamic programming.  Just increase length of your array by 1 on every step.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I am not very sure about that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't understand how you found the pattern `{1, 1}` in the array `{1, 2, 1}`?

Comment: @JimMischel I tried to specify the problem a little bit. If it's still unclear, please let me know. Thanks.